# ASP Core PatchDocument returning Invalid Input

Tags: angular, asp.net-core

I want to use JsonPatchDocument to update models that were changed on the Angular 6 front end.
Unfortunately i keep receiving 400 Bad Request response with following message:

```
{"":["The input was not valid."]}
```

Now i am not sure if i am doing this properly but this is how my code is setup:

Frontend:

```
edit.ts class

onSubmit() {
    this.testService.update(this.id, this.prepareFormModel())
      .subscribe(res => console.info(res);
  }

  prepareFormModel() {
    const formModel = this.testForm.value;

    const retVal: any = {
      title: formModel.title as string,
      comment: formModel.comment ? formModel.comment : '' as string,
      qualified: formModel.qualified as boolean
    };

    return retVal;
  }
```

test.service.ts class

```
constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  update(id: string, value: any): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.patch<any>('http://localhost:5001/api/test' + '/' + id, value);
  }
```

in my ASP CORE Project Test Controller

```
    [HttpPatch("{id}")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> UpdateModel(Guid id, [FromBody]JsonPatchDocument<TestModel> modelDocument)
    {            
        return Ok();
    }
```

The DTO model

```
    public class TestModel
    {
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Comment { get; set; }
        public bool Qualified { get; set; } 
    }
```

Any idea as to what i am stuffing up?

**Update 1:**

I noticed that httpclient patch only sends out content type application/json. Looking at some examples of JsonPatchDocument it seems to request application/json-patch+json type.

Comment: Have you tried changing the case, so that they match? i.e., both use `title` or both use `Title`

Comment: yup, did that test as well

Comment: Have you tried to copy the HTTP body into Postman to test the API first? Better use 'console.log(value);' to check the input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your current code, you misunderstood `JsonPatchDocument` which is used to describe exactly how you want to modify a document (For example, replace the value in a field with another value) without having to also send along the rest of the unchanged values.

You currently passing the `prepareFormModel` instead of describing how you want to modify `formModel`.

If you want to get `TestModel` directly in `UpdateModel`, you need to remove `JsonPatchDocument`.

```
    public async Task<IActionResult> UpdateModelWithOutJsonPatch(Guid id, [FromBody]TestModel modelDocument)
    {
        return Ok();
    }
```

If you want to implement `JsonPatchDocument` which is descripted in [JSON Patch With ASP.net Core](https://dotnetcoretutorials.com/2017/11/29/json-patch-asp-net-core/), you need to pass document description, for a json path library, you could try `fast-json-patch`.

- API

  ```
      public async Task<IActionResult> UpdateModelWithJsonPatch(Guid id, [FromBody]JsonPatchDocument<TestModel> modelDocument)
  {
      return Ok();
  }
  ```
- install package

  ```
    npm install fast-json-patch --save
  ```
- import the functions

  ```
  import { compare } from 'fast-json-patch';
  ```
- Compare objects and passing eh jsonpatch object.

```js
export class FetchDataComponent {
  public forecasts: WeatherForecast[];
  constructor(http: HttpClient, @Inject('BASE_URL') baseUrl: string) {
    const patch = compare(this.previousFormModel(), this.prepareFormModel());
    http.patch<any>(baseUrl + 'api/SampleData/UpdateModelWithJsonPatch/1', patch).subscribe(result => {
      console.log(result);
    }, error => console.error(error));;

    http.patch<any>(baseUrl + 'api/SampleData/UpdateModelWithOutJsonPatch/1', this.prepareFormModel()).subscribe(result =>     {
      console.log(result);
    }, error => console.error(error));;

  }
  previousFormModel() {
    //const formModel = this.testForm.value;
    const retVal: any = {
      title: "t2" as string,
      comment: "c2" as string,
      qualified: false as boolean
    };
    return retVal;
  }
  prepareFormModel() {    //const formModel = this.testForm.value;

    const retVal: any = {
      title: "t1" as string,
      comment: "c1" as string,
      qualified: true as boolean
    };
    return retVal;
  }
}
```

**Note**, for `JsonPatch`, you will need to implement something like below to get `TestModel`

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
 public class PersonController : Controller
 {
private readonly Person _defaultPerson = new Person
{
    FirstName = "Jim",
    LastName = "Smith"
};

[HttpPatch("update")]
public Person Patch([FromBody]JsonPatchDocument<Person> personPatch)
{
    personPatch.ApplyTo(_defaultPerson);
    return _defaultPerson;
}
}
```